# How to send mails from Java mail API from a server not having internet connection and using web server?

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using JAVA mail API to send mails and using SMTP. When I am putting the code in the test server it is successfully sending mails as it is having internet connection. But in the production there is no internet connection. Is it possible to send mails using the web server? The code that I am using to send mails is as follows.

```
final String username = "momkutty@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    System.out.println("Setting properties");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.google.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    System.out.println("Properties set successfully");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
    });
    try {
    System.out.println("Setting message properties");
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("momkutty@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("sumankalyan.roy@cmcltd.com"));
    message.setSubject("Test Subject");
    message.setText("Hey!!!! This is a TEST mail using SMTP SMTP port no.25.....");
    System.out.println("Going to send mail...");
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Mail has been Sent");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }e
```

Comment: I don't understand "the production there is no internet connection". So your server only serves your LAN right?, you would need a mail server in your LAN that has access to the internet. I don't think this is a a java question. It's more an infrastructure question. And, no a web server is not a mail server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SOCKS proxy server, see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).

If you only have a web proxy server, you might need something like [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using my web server IP as "socksProxyHost" and 1080 as "socksProxyPort"...!! refer the following lines....!

```
props.setProperty("proxySet","true");
props.setProperty("socksProxyHost","10.10.30.146");
props.setProperty("socksProxyPort","1080");
```

and trying to send mails through port no. 587...!!

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

but it says..

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.cmcltd.vtms.sms.smsalert.SmsEmailAlerts.testMail(SmsEmailAlerts.java:1029)
    at com.cmcltd.vtms.sms.smsalert.ScheduleJob.execute(ScheduleJob.java:25)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 10 more
```

Is it because the 587 port is blocked in the web server? Or there is something wrong in the code...!!?